# detailed account of government borrowing and fed open market operations

Tags: monetary-policy, government-debt

I would like to read an *extremely* detailed (yet, if possible, accessible) account of exactly what happens when the US government borrows money -- how rates are negotiated, who exactly the counterparties are, how the debt they've bought is represented, which accounts are credited etc.

I would also like an *extremely* detailed account of exactly what happens when the Fed does open market operations -- all the same details as above.

What's a good resource?